# How to scale a rectangle with rounded corners in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

the scale handles disappear when i round a rectangle's corners

how can I increase/decrease the size with no handles?

Answer (score 1):

When you select an object with the black arrow tool it shows the bounding box with scale nodes at each corner and on each side.

When you select an object with the white arrow tool you see only the object's anchor points.

Make sure the object is unlocked and on the active layer.

You can access and adjust the round corner settings in the Appearances tab.

Any effect you've applied can be isolated, edited or deleted in the Appearances tab.

If you want to scale the whole rectangle then select it with the black arrow tool and the scale handles should be there.

If not, try expanding, this gives back the ability to scale but you cant change the round on the corners anymore.

Comment: How can I expand the object? are there keyboard shortcuts to increase/decrease the entire object (proportionally and disproportionally)?

Comment: To expand you select the object, click Object>Expand Appearance>Okay. I don't know any keys to auto resize objects, there probably are, here's a key to illustrator shortcuts:  https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/illustrator/pdf/Ai_cheat-sheet_Windows.jpg

Comment: However I use several methods to resize, proportionally and not. 1. drag a corner with the black arrow tool, hold down shift to keep it proportional. 2. Use the H and W windows in the tool bar, enter new height or width. have the chain link checked to keep it proportional. 3. Use the transform functions: Object?Transform>Scale, there is uniform and non-uniform. Number 2 allows you to be very exact by specifying height or width to the pixel.